# Python socket recv buffer handling

Tags: python, linux, sockets, buffer

Im attempting to speed up socket handling in python using a buffer/queue 
below an implementation for cyclic buffer I use to read max size out of localhost socket used for IPC

```
class BufferHandling:
def __init__(self, buffer_size, max_chunk_size):
    self._read_index = 0
    self._write_index = 0

    self._buffer = bytearray(buffer_size)
    self._mem_view = memoryview(self._buffer)
    self._max_size = max_chunk_size

def fill_from_socket(self, _socket):
    logging.debug("2 fill: write index %s , read_index %s", self._write_index , self._read_index)
    if self._read_index > self._write_index:
        if self._read_index - self._write_index < self._max_size:
            raise RuntimeError("no place to write in buffer")

        ret = _socket.recv_into(self._mem_view[self._write_index:], self._max_size)
        self._write_index += ret
        #logging.debug("1 recv_from return with %s, write index %s", ret, self._write_index)
        return

    # write >= read
    _1st_write_size = len(self._mem_view) - self._write_index
    _2nd_write_size = self._read_index

    if _1st_write_size + _2nd_write_size < self._max_size:
        raise RuntimeError("no place to write in buffer")

    if _1st_write_size >= self._max_size:
        ret = _socket.recv_into(self._mem_view[self._write_index:], self._max_size)
        self._write_index += ret
        #logging.debug("2 recv_from return with %s , write index %s", ret, self._write_index)
        return

    # clear some room ...

    self._mem_view[:self._write_index - self._read_index] = self._mem_view[self._read_index: self._write_index]
    self._write_index = self._write_index - self._read_index
    self._read_index = 0
    ret = _socket.recv_into(self._mem_view[self._write_index:], self._max_size)
    self._write_index += ret
    logging.debug("3 recv_from return with %s, write index %s", ret, self._write_index)

"""
# read data from cyclic buffer
# if data found , return data according to _to_read size
# else return empty string
"""
def read_from_buffer(self, _to_read):
    logging.debug("1 write_index %s , read_index %s , _to_read %s", self._write_index, self._read_index, _to_read)
    if self._read_index > self._write_index:
        _1st_read_size = len(self._mem_view) - self._read_index
        _2nd_read_size = self._write_index

        if _1st_read_size >= _to_read:
            data = self._buffer[self._read_index: self._read_index + _to_read]
            self._read_index += _to_read

        else:
            data = self._buffer[self._read_index:] + self._buffer[:_to_read - _1st_read_size]
            self._read_index = _to_read - _1st_read_size
    else: # write >= read
        _read_less = min(_to_read, self._write_index - self._read_index)

        # if self._write_index - self._read_index < _to_read:
        #   logging.debug("2 write_index %s , read_index %s , _to_read %s", self._write_index,self._read_index,_to_read)
        #   #return None

        logging.debug("2 write_index %s , read_index %s , _to_read %s, _read %s", self._write_index, self._read_index, _to_read, _read_less)

        data = self._buffer[self._read_index: self._read_index + _read_less]
        self._read_index += _read_less

    return data
```

I using it like:

```
        self.__buffer = BufferHandling(self.__LOCALHOST_SOCKET_BUFFER_LEN * 4, 
self.__LOCALHOST_SOCKET_BUFFER_LEN)
data = self.__buffer.read_from_buffer(_to_read)
        if len(data) < _to_read:
            self._selector.select(rlist = [self.__connection], elist = [self.__connection])
            self.__buffer.fill_from_socket(self.__connection)
            data += self.__buffer.read_from_buffer(_to_read)
```

After facing many issues, my question: is there a more `Pythonic` way to get the same affect? 
or maybe suggest a more "clean" way to get some form of `io buffering`

Comment: Why? You can't process data more quickly than it arrives. Receiving is network-bound. Circular buffering won't help. Your best strategy is to use a large socket receive buffer size and a large local buffer to receive into so you aren't calling `recv` too often, but you don't need a circular buffer for that. Keep it simple.

Comment: Agreed; it's not clear that this code is attempting to do anything that the TCP stacks own built-in buffering system doesn't already do; if that's true, then simply increasing the size of the socket's built-in receive buffer would provide the same benefits.  (Note that if even the TCP stack's largest receive-buffer-size isn't big enough for you, you can obtain an effectively unlimited receive-buffer by creating a separate I/O thread that does nothing but call `recv()` and store the received data into a FIFO queue of some sort, which your regular thread can then process at its leisure)

Comment: I missed to info , I have a udp server that is sending huge amount of data that Im not able to control , thus I need to maximize the CPU/IO usage so TCP is out of the question, trying to read and interact directly with socket.recv_into failed due to packet drop , another thread I didn't try because I felt the queue overhead was too much, there must be a "nicer" way to do that

Answer (score 0):

I have created a short method to "clear" the buffer of a UDP socket. Here is the code:

```
def empty(sock):
    """Empty the UDP buffer."""
    sock.setblocking(0)
    while True:
        try:
            sock.recv(1024)
        except BlockingIOError:
            sock.setblocking(1)
            return
```